# I want to upgrade my sonarqube server4.1 to latest version sonarqube 5.1?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I want to upgrade sonarqube 4.1 to latest version(5.1).So what steps i need to do and follow?
and what is the best strategy to upgrade server?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try to install a previous version, for example 5.0.1. If this work then install the newest version.

Download SonarQube: http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

1. stop sonar
2. make a DB backup
3. rename 4.1 sonar folder
4. unzip downloaded SonarQube zip file (e.g. `sonarqube-5.1.1.zip`)
5. modify `sonar.properties` and `wrapper.conf` files located in `<SONAR_HOME>/conf` (don't replace the files, modify parameters)
6. copy plugins to `<SONAR_HOME>/extensions/plugins` (check [plugins matrix compatibility](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix))
7. copy drivers to `<SONAR_HOME>/extensions/drivers`
8. modify `<SONAR_HOME>` in service file, e.g `/etc/init.d/sonar`
9. start sonar
10. verify logs in `<SONAR_HOME>/logs`
11. open http://:/setup
12. click upgrade button and wait

Answer (score 1):

Everything is on the [SonarQube wiki](http://docs.sonarqube.org/): http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading